# Unable to find activity,have you declared in manifest

Tags: android

I am trying to implement pdf viewer in my app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ttech"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
         android:name="com.example.ttech.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen"
        >
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ttech.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ttech.NewLogin"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_login" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ttech.HomePage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home_page" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ttech.Audio"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_audio" >
    </activity>
   <activity android:name=".PdfViewerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pdf_viewer"
        >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ttech.Feedback"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_feedback" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ttech.Profile"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ttech.AboutUs"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about_us" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ttech.Contact"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_contact" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ttech.LogOut"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_log_out" >
    </activity>
    <activity
         android:name="com.example.ttech.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        >
    </activity>
</application>
```

The error is I am getting is:-

```
E/AndroidRuntime(828): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.ttech/net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity}; have you declared this activity in your Android manifest
```

Comment: it is saying activity ur trying to access is not declare in your manifest file

Comment: You have not declare your viewer activity.

Answer (score 2):

You declared the activity as

```
<activity android:name=".PdfViewerActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_pdf_viewer" />
```

Since you defined `package="com.example.ttech"`, the activity points to the class `com.example.ttech.PdfViewerActivity`, but you want to use `net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity` instead.

Therefore you have to define the activity with an absolute package name

```
<activity android:name="net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_pdf_viewer" />
```

Comment: after declaring like this,i'm getting error                                                    09-10 06:32:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(843): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 06:32:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(843): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ttech/net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity

Comment: The stacktrace tells you the reasons for this exceptions. Not only the message. But it tells me, that at least your first issue is resolved...